# Initialializing a struct with predefined values

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct naming
    {
        int numline;
        string numname;
    } naming = {{1,"ONE"},{2,"TWO"}};
  cout<<naming.numline<<":"<<naming.numname<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

This error occurs:

```
main.cpp:10:33: error: braces around scalar initializer for type int
} naming = {{1,"ONE"},{2,"TWO"}};
```

Comment: What do you expect the code to do?

Comment: Fixed. thks juanchopanza found naming[] is correct, not just naming. Access the elements using array index as given in @C0smo reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
struct naming { … } naming = …
```

which means you're creating a single `naming` object. But your initializer

```
{{1,"ONE"},{2,"TWO"}}
```

doesn't match that intent.

Looks like you're trying to initialize a collection of `naming` objects. If that's the case you should make it a `std::vector<naming>` instead of a single object:

```
struct naming { … }; // definition of naming
std::vector<naming> namings = {{1, "ONE"}, {2, "TWO"}}; // collection of objects
```

Then you can access the individual naming objects like so:

```
// access the first element:
std::cout << namings.at(0).numline << ":" << namings.at(0).numname << std::endl;
// access the second element:
std::cout << namings.at(1).numline << ":" << namings.at(1).numname << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to store two values , you will have to create an array of structure type.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct naming
    {
        int numline;
        string numname;
    } naming[] = {{1,"ONE"},{2,"TWO"}};
    cout<<naming[0].numline<<":"<<naming[0].numname<<std::endl;
    cout<<naming[1].numline<<":"<<naming[1].numname<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works in the compiler in my head. Thanks! @zenith solution is very good also. zenith's is the one I am going to use since I may not want to hardcode there are only two elements in naming[].